# Cluster node fails to start

Tags: neo4j, installation, cluster-computing, high-availability

I am trying to setup a Neo4j HA cluster using the Enterprise version 2.1.5.
Everything works just fine when I setup a cluster locally.
However, when I try to use different machines to form the cluster one node fails to start and simply keeps still after writing `INFO  [Cluster] Write transactions to database disabled` to the console log file. In my case the master stucks while the slave tries to join the cluster.

What can cause this behaviour?

## Configuration

### Master

**conf/neo4j.properties**

```
ha.server_id=1
ha.cluster_server=<ip:m>:5001
ha.initial_hosts=<ip:m>:5001,<ip:s>:5001
ha.server=<ip:m>:6001
```

**conf/neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=<ip:m>
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7484
```

### Slave

**conf/neo4j.properties**

```
ha.server_id=2
ha.cluster_server=<ip:s>:5001
ha.initial_hosts=<ip:m>:5001,<ip:s>:5001
ha.server=<ip:s>:6001
ha.slave_only=true
```

**conf/neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=<ip:s>
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7484
```

## Console/log files output

### Master

**terminal**

```
$ sudo /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
HA instance started in process [30188]. Will be operational once connected to peers. See /var/lib/neo4j/data/log/console.log for current status.

**data/log/console.log**
2014-11-25 10:13:48.759+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Write transactions to database disabled

**data/log/neo4j.0.0.log**
**file is empty**

### Slave

**terminal**

```
$ sudo su
$ /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...HA instance started in process [4057]. Will be operational once connected to peers. See /var/lib/neo4j/data/log/console.log for current status.

**data/log/console.log**
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
2014-11-25 10:17:23.427+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Write transactions to database disabled
2014-11-25 10:17:24.402+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Attempting to join cluster of [`<ip:m>`:5001, `<ip:s>`:5001]

**data/log/neo4j.0.0.log**
**file is empty**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cluster needs to have at least 3 instances since a master election requires a quorum (more than half). Try to setup a third instance to solve this and amend the 3rd instance to `initial_hosts`. Be sure to have the 3 instances on the same network or use a vpn for this.

Comment: I found the documentation on this really lacking (and confusing when considering http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-availability.html). Worth mentioning Arbiter instances?

Comment: I think this is not pointed out very well in the documentation. Though 3 nodes are used in every example, the overview page suggests one master with zero or more slaves. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-architecture.html However, in my local test 2 nodes did form a cluster. Why is that?

Comment: @JohnMark13: arbiter instance are intended for corner cases. A regular HA deployment should have a minimum of 3 instances.

Comment: @SebastianSchlicht when using only 2 instances you won't have HA. To survive n failures you need 2n+1 instances.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster: I would intuit this to be the case, but the documentation states that "Neo4j HA is fault tolerant and can continue to operate from any number of machines down to a single machine." I wonder how a master knows whether it should block writes or not if it cannot see the salve and arbiter.

Comment: the cluster manager component knows who's available. If we have a quorum a master can be elected. If quorum is not reached, writes are impossible but reads are still fine.